# How to use a useState in react-hooks with percentage and conditions?

Tags: reactjs

i'm a new student on react library and i have a doubt with a question in react-hooks...

let's see

im trying to make a new component that ask a first name, last name and participation in the company, and the participation do not pass 100% but whenever I put a value on the form it change,
I was wondering if there is a way to save data from this input so that only users can make up to 100% of the company

the code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(' ');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(' ');
  const [participation, setParticipation] = useState([]);
  
  const handlePartner = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      participation
    }
    
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="header">
        <form action="" onSubmit={handlePartner}>
              <input type="text"  placeholder="First Name" value={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}/>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value={lastName} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}/>
              <input type="number" placeholder="Participation" value={participation} onChange={e => 
              e.target.value <= 100 && e.target.value >= 0 ? setParticipation(e.target.value) : null}
                />
              <button type="submit">SEND</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="data">
        <h1>DATA</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsur dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

[Image of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vqN1.png)

I am very grateful for the help

Comment: What is suppose to happen when you submit the form? Right now, nothing happens.

Comment: I didn't really understand the question you want to solve, are you asking "how to save data" ? Or "how to check if a user is loggedin before updating the value" ?

Comment: Hi, i'm asking if there is a way to save the useState data, because every time I change the user and the participation number it overwrites the previous participation number, in the the code doesn't actually do anything at the moment, but i would like to know if there is a way to save this data as if it were an accumulator so when it reached 100 it would not accept more input

Comment: @jinwar how to save data from the input, sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save data from the input, you have to build another app to handle data. You will usually use node.js, python, java, c++ ...

I strongly recommend node.js for a simple reason: it is the same language as react.js (javascript). A lot faster to maintain.

Once you have your back (linked to a database), you have to make an endpoint (like /save/user/data), that will handle the logic. For now I won't talk you about separation and logic, just make it work for now.

Once you have your endpoint, you have to send information from the front to the back.

Your form will have an onSubmit event, like you did.

In your function / class method you have to extract data from the form, check if it's ok, then send it to the back. To send it to the back you can use a normal fetch like this :

```
const fetched: any = await fetch(yourUrl, display), {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
      data1: value1,
      data2: value2,
      data3: value3
  }),
});
```

**Edit: I just saw what you are actually looking for, I will let above answer in case it also helps you**

You can add a 'totalValue' in your state, and in your onSubmit event handler you can update state like this :

```
this.setState(previousState => ({
    totalValue: previousState.totalValue + newValueToAdd,
}));
```

then your value is increasing every time you validate the form.

Comment: hi @jinwar, thanks for the help, the answer helped me so much. idk that was possible, so thank you!

Comment: also don't forget state change is asynchronous, which means the new state won't be available "under" setState right away, you have either to use a callback like this : this.setState(previousState => ({
    totalValue: previousState.totalValue + newValueToAdd,
}), () => {  this is your callback function, called after the state has changed  }); or make the function that updates state synchronous (with async) and use await in front of setState